# "groupby" returning the percent of occurrences based on a certain condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Based on a dataframe similar to

```
Strategy    Profit
AA          100 
AA           50
AA          -50
BB          -20
BB          180
CC          -20
DD           20
```

I would like to groupby "Strategy" and have the percent of time "Profit" is positive (i.e. bigger than zero - the condition).

I currently do this quite rustically (looping through the strategies), but I need a more straightforward approach because there are too many records, with too many different "Strategies".

```
df.groupby("Strategy")["Profit"].count() # total of ocurrences per "strategy"
df[df["Profit"] > 0].groupby("Strategy")["Profit"].count() # total of positive results
```

Expected result:

```
Strategy   Assertiveiness %
AA           66,66 
BB              50
CC               0
DD             100
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why is `BB` 90, shouldn't it be 50?

Comment: @user3483203 Correct! Fixed! Thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just `groupby` + `mean`

```
df["Profit"].gt(0).groupby(df["Strategy"]).mean().mul(100)

Strategy
AA     66.666667
BB     50.000000
CC      0.000000
DD    100.000000
Name: Profit, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The secret (for me) actually was `gt(0)`. Thanks! 