# “groupby” returning the percent of occurrences of each grouped item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This one is similar to [my own previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251908/groupby-returning-the-percent-of-occurrences-based-on-a-certain-condition/66251967#66251967).

If I perform the following `groupby`, I get the `count()` of each `factor`.

```
df.groupby("factor")["factor"].count()
```

Output:

```
factor
0       2000
1        500
2       1000
3        100
```

Is there a way to get the % of records belonging to each factor. Expected:

```
factor
0       55,55
1       13,88
2       27,77
3        2,77
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize parameter might help you:

```
df['factor'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```